Baby fake eating
So I have a 3 week old, born 7 days before term, 3.5kg on birth, lost almost 400g in the hospital, then returned to 3.5kg in about 10 days. Since then he has gained an additional 200g, which I fear is not enough.
We are struggling with his eating.
He wakes up about every 3 hours, and I first let him breastfeed for about 30 mins (which is a struggle in itself since he just falls asleep at the boob). After that  (because I don't think he eats enough just breastfeeding) I either give him formula or breastmilk that I pumped. That's where the really annoying part begins, because most of the time he just pretends to eat, he will be sucking for 20 mins and when I check the bottle, I see that he has not eaten a single drop. He then eithet falls asleep, or is just nervous and refuses to eat/sleep, which is frustrating both because I worry about his weight gain, bit aldo because most of my pumped milk just goes to the trash.
Please help if you have any advice.

Maybe you need to set your priority: is the major worry weight gain or not wasting breast milk? Giving him extra time to feed (possibly) or to get more sleep? Because the way you're doing it now, they're contradictory. Either stop giving the extra bottle after nursing (i.e. stop worrying over the weight gain and let your HCP advise you), or stop being frustrated that the infant is using it as a pacifier. (Posted as a comment because it's a frame challenge.)

Your baby is 3 weeks old and gained 200 grams in the last 10 days? I would say he is doing perfectly fine, don't stress out. Talk to your midwife or your family doctor for extra reassurance but this doesn't look like a reason to worry to me at all.
